# how to get toTraceString() from linq to entities query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
dynamic traceFile =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\EntityFrameworkTrace.log";                
var CurrentStock = (from s in DBViews.StockStatus
                    where s.ProductID != 10
                    orderby s.ProductName
                    select new
                    {
                        s.ProductID,
                        s.ProductName,
                        CurrentStock = s.TotalStocked - s.TotalSold,
                        s.CurrentSellingRate,
                        CashValue = (s.TotalStocked - s.TotalSold) * s.CurrentSellingRate,
                        s.LastStocked,
                        s.LastCostPrice,
                        s.LastQtyStocked
                    }).ToList();

File.AppendAllText(traceFile, CurrentStock.toTraceString());   
return CurrentStock.ToList();
```

How can get toTraceString() from CurrentStock on in the following line? it ain't being resolved

```
File.AppendAllText(traceFile,  CurrentStock.toTraceString());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot because you have already called `ToList` - it is not a Linq-to-Entities query but simply a `List` instance.

Try this:

```
var CurrentStock = (from s in DBViews.StockStatus
                    where s.ProductID != 10
                    orderby s.ProductName
                    select new
                    {
                        s.ProductID,
                        s.ProductName,
                        CurrentStock = s.TotalStocked - s.TotalSold,
                        s.CurrentSellingRate,
                        CashValue = (s.TotalStocked - s.TotalSold) * s.CurrentSellingRate,
                        s.LastStocked,
                        s.LastCostPrice,
                        s.LastQtyStocked
                    }); // No ToList here!

File.AppendAllText(traceFile, ((ObjectQuery)CurrentStock).ToTraceString());   
return CurrentStock.ToList();
```

Btw. why are you using `dynamic` instead of `string`? Dynamic type is only for special cases where that makes sense - this is not the case.